# issue decoding an image using jpeg_js

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, tensorflow.js

my environment:

```
ubuntu 18.04
rtx 2080ti
cuda 10.1
node v12.16.3 
tfjs 1.7.4
```

the saved_model is [efficientdet-d0](https://storage.googleapis.com/cloud-tpu-checkpoints/efficientdet/coco/efficientdet-d0.tar.gz),
and the step of inference is in [inference step](https://github.com/google/automl/blob/master/efficientdet/README.md#5-inference-for-images)

for parsing image data with js,i convert img.png to img.jpg,and the result of saved_model is same with [saved_model result](https://github.com/google/automl/blob/master/efficientdet/g3doc/street.jpg)
the command convert saved_model to tfjs_graph_model is

```
tensorflowjs_converter --input_format=tf_saved_model /tmp/saved_model ~/DATA/http_models/specDetection/
```

and my test code is

```
var tfc = require("@tensorflow/tfjs-converter");
var tf  = require("@tensorflow/tfjs-core");
var jpeg_js = require("jpeg-js");
var fs = require("fs");


async function loadModel() {
    var modelUrl = "http://localhost:8000/model.json"
    var model = await tfc.loadGraphModel(modelUrl);
    return model;
}

async function detect() {
    var model = await loadModel();
    var img = fs.readFileSync("~/SRC/automl_test/efficientdet/img.jpg");
    const input = jpeg_js.decode(img,{useTArray:true,formatAsRGBA:false});

    const batched = tf.tidy(() => {
        const img = tf.browser.fromPixels(input);
        // Reshape to a single-element batch so we can pass it to executeAsync.
        return img.expandDims(0);
    });

    const result = await model.executeAsync({'image_arrays:0':batched},['detections:0']);
    console.log(result);
}

detect();
```

when detect object in img.jpg with my test code,nothing detected --- the size of result is 0
what do i do to sovle this problem?
thanks for any cue

edit:
code 1:

```
 var img = fs.readFileSync("~/DATA/http_models/specDetection/test.jpg");

    var dataJpegJs = jpeg_js.decode(img,{useTArray:true,formatAsRGBA:false})
    var batched = tf.browser.fromPixels({data:dataJpegJs.data, width: dataJpegJs.width, height:dataJpegJs.height},3);
    batched = batched.slice([0,0,0],[-1,-1,3]);
    var result = await model.executeAsync({'image_arrays:0':batched.expandDims(0)},['detections:0']);
    result = tf.slice(result,[0,0,1],[1,-1,4]);
```

code 2:

```
var img = fs.readFileSync("~/DATA/http_models/specDetection/test.jpg");

    var dataJpegJs = jpeg_js.decode(img,{useTArray:true,formatAsRGBA:true})
    var batched = tf.browser.fromPixels({data:dataJpegJs.data, width: dataJpegJs.width, height:dataJpegJs.height},4);
    batched = batched.slice([0,0,0],[-1,-1,3]);
    var result = await model.executeAsync({'image_arrays:0':batched.expandDims(0)},['detections:0']);
    result = tf.slice(result,[0,0,1],[1,-1,4]);
```

code 1 got a bad result and code 2 got a correct result.
code 2 decode jpg with formatAsRGBA:true,and set numChannels=4 in tf.browser.fromPixels.  jpeg-js must decode jpg to RGBA to work correctly.
i think it is a bug of jpeg-js.or i am not familiar with jpg encoding?

Comment: Are you sure you are doing the same preprocessing in both scenarios?

Comment: thanks for your reply. i use @edkeveked code , and it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tensor is not well generated. `fromPixels` is mostly used to get a tensor from an `htmlImageElement`. Printing a summary of the tensor and compare it with the one generated for python can suffice to tell that.

Is there an issue with jpeg-js ?

First we need to know how the imageData works. An image Data pixel is a 4 numerical values R, G, B, A. When using the data decoded by jpeg_js.decode as argument of tf.browser.fromPixel with 3 channels (formatAsRGBA:false), it is considered as an image data. Let's consider the data `[a, b, c, d, e, f] = jpeg_js.decode("path", {formatAsRGBA:false})` and the tensor t created from it
`t = tf.browser.fromPixels({data, width: 2, height: 1})`. How it is interpreted ? `tf.browser.fromPixels`, will create an ImageDate of height: 1 and of width: 2. Consequently, the imageData will be of size 1 * 2 * 4 (instead of 1 * 2 * 3) and has all its values set to 0. Then it will copy the data decoded to the imageData. So `imageData = [a, b, c, d, e, f, 0, 0]`.
As a result, the slice (t.slice([0, 0, 0], [-1, -1, 3]) will be `[a, b, c, e, f, 0]`.
Neither is `jpeg_js` the issue, nor `tf.browser.fromPixels`. This is how imageData works

What can be done ?

- keep the alpha channel of the decoded image `formatAsRGBA:true`
- Instead of using tf.browser.fromPixels, use directly tf.tensor to create the tensor

```js
const img = tf.tensor(input.data, [input.height, input.width, 3])
```

---

Another option is to use`tensorflow-node`. And `tf.node.decodeImage` can decode an image from a tensor.

```js
const img = fs.readFileSync("path/of/image");
const tensor = tf.node.decodeImage(img)
// use the tensor for prediction
```

Unlike `jpeg-js` that works only for image in jpeg encoding format, it can decode a wider range of images

Comment: thank you very much for  your reply. it is a bug of fromPixels. i use your code and it works. my environment is not node, i will find another way to decode image to tensor. thanks for your reply again.

Comment: what is your environment ?

Comment: my environment is wechat miniprogram.  sorry for my mistake, it is a bug of jpeg-js actually

Comment: whatever the environment it looks like a superset of nodejs. I don't think that it is a bug of `jpeg-js`. You are simply using `tf.browser.fromPixels` in a wrong way. See my updated answer with `jpeg-js`

Comment: i compared difference decode option with jpeg-js. See my update in question . i think it is a bug of jpeg-js . or i am not familiar with jpg encoding?

Comment: There is no bug. Please see my edited answer. If it helped don't forget to accept it and mark it as accepted ;)