# Jimp image to Tensor node.js

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I am using `Tensorflow.js` model. Model receives image in a `Jimp` format.

I need to convert `Jimp` bitmap to 4d Tensor.

So far I have tried this `toTensor` function:

```
function imageByteArray (image){
    
    const numChannels = 3;

    const numPixels = image.bitmap.width * image.bitmap.height;
    const values = new Int32Array(numPixels * numChannels);


    image.scan(0, 0, image.bitmap.width, image.bitmap.height, function(x, y, idx){

        values[y * image.bitmap.width * numChannels + x * numChannels + 0] = this.bitmap.data[idx + 0];
        values[y * image.bitmap.width * numChannels + x * numChannels + 1] = this.bitmap.data[idx + 1];
        values[y * image.bitmap.width * numChannels + x * numChannels + 2] = this.bitmap.data[idx + 2];

    });


    return values
}
  
function toTensor(image){
    const values = imageByteArray(image);
    // const values = image.data;
    const outShape = [1, image.bitmap.height, image.bitmap.width, 3];
    const input = tf.tensor4d(values, outShape, 'float32');

    return input.sub(127.5).div(128.0)

}
```

But when I compare original pre-processing (implemented during training stage) using python `cv2`:

```
def process(image):

    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

    image = image.astype("float32")

    image = (image - 127.5) / 128.0


    return image.reshape((1, width, height, 3))
```

But there are some small differences in input.

> Is there any correct method to convert `jimp` image to RGB tensor

Comment: Could you not direclty use tf.node.btmap to decode the image ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tf.node` can allow to decode the bitmap encoded image as already indicated in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62148637/issue-decoding-an-image-using-jpeg-js)

```
const img = fs.readFileSync("path/of/image");
const tensor = tf.node.decodeImage(img)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to convert `jimp` image to `tfnode.Tensor`:

```
function preProcess(image){
    // const values = imageByteArray(image);
    const values = image.bitmap.data;
    const outShape = [1, image.bitmap.width, image.bitmap.height, 4];
    var input = tf.tensor4d(values, outShape, 'float32');
    
    // Slice away alpha
    input = input.slice([0, 0, 0, 0], [1, image.bitmap.width, image.bitmap.height, 3]);


    return input;

}
```

Jimp image usually contains `alpha` values as well, So I maked `4D` Tensor containing alpha values as well, then `sliced` RGB only values.

As @edkeveked said. I can use `tf.node.decodeImage` functionality, but my main preprocessing (during training) was on opencv, so I needed to make sure it was as close to opencv implementation.

I also found some [problems](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/24893) with `tensorflow` image functions.

So I opt to not use tensorflow image functions.

Comment: The issue you mentionned is irrelevant to your image conversion to a tensor. The issue is created on the python version. So using tf.js should not change the tensor created. Besides why use several modules if we can do the same with less ?